# TypeScript 5.2 won't accept a literal string

Tags: javascript, typescript

The ElasticSearch API 7.12 for NodeJS defines an `index` method which takes certain options in the form of a `params` parameter defined as the [Index](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/e5b589d7a5a0f30f7ea61819b384eb12938f7bcf/api/requestParams.d.ts#L902) interface. This is an object which has the a property `refresh` which accepts a string `'wait_for'` or a `boolean`:

```js
export interface Index<T = RequestBody> extends Generic {
  id?: string;
  refresh?: 'wait_for' | boolean;
}
```

However, when we pass the string `wait_for` - typescript complains that this is incompatible:

```js
let options = {};
options.refresh = 'wait_for';
await ES.update({id, index, ...options});
```

#### TypeScript 5.2

```bash
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(params?: Update<{ doc: any; doc_as_upsert: boolean; script: any; scripted_upsert: any; }>, options?: TransportRequestOptions): TransportRequestPromise<ApiResponse<Record<string, any>, unknown>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ refresh: string; id: any; index: any; body: { doc: any; doc_as_upsert: true; script: any; scripted_upsert: any; }; retry_on_conflict: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Update<{ doc: any; doc_as_upsert: boolean; script: any; scripted_upsert: any; }>'.
      Types of property 'refresh' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | "wait_for"'.
```

It only accepts a boolean - then the code compiles:

```js
options.refresh = true;
```

Interestingly, if we refactor slightly it works:

```js
let options = {id};
options.refresh = 'wait_for';
await ES.update({index, ...options});
```

In summary, as soon as options is an empty object `{}` the parser fails unless refresh is a boolean.

Note:

- our code is JavaScript with a jsconfig.json to do type checking.
- we're interested in why the parser fails here (and if this could be a TS bug) not how to work around the issue
- Possibly [related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16259)

Comment: Can you use JSDoc to tell TS that `options` is an `Index` of some kind? Or that `'wait_for` is `as const`?

Comment: Not easily (we would need to import complex ES types). However I don't think it would help. IMO TS is contradicting itsself with `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | "wait_for"'.`

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] we could use to see this for ourselves in our own IDEs? (All the referenced types/values should be declared in some way, for example.)  And maybe add a link to a web IDE that demonstrates it?  The issue is almost certainly that TS is inferring `string` instead of `"wait_for"` (which is usually what people want for string-valued object properties, but it bites you here).  But I don't see how that would change when you refactor it slightly... I'd love to see this behavior myself before venturing a guess.